Invertibility of sub matrix and rank of matrix
Let A be a non-null matrix.
a) Show that a submatrix of A formed by the rows in a row basis of A and the columns in a column basis of A, is invertible. Deduce that the rank of A is the maximum k for which A has a invertible submatrix of order k.
b) Show that a submatrix of A formed by k linearly independent rows and k linearly independent columns need not be invertible.
I am not being able to understand the meaning of the question. In the first part does it mean that we reduce the n x n matrix to a r x n matrix where r is the rank of the matrix and only keep the basis vectors as the rows. Then reduce this r x n to a r x r matrix by keeping the r column basis? If so then how do I show that this is full row rank or full column rank?
